# react-native - TouchableHighlight: Remove highlighting after onPress?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, touchablehighlight

I am developing a simple react-native app and am encountering an issue on TouchableHighlight:

When pressing the `TouchableHighlight`, a new screen is displayed (using StackNavigator from `react-navigation`). After pressing the back-button and returning to the original screen, the `TouchableHighlight` still has a black background-color - meaning, that it is still highlighted.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to manually deactivate the highlighting of a `TouchableHighlight`-component? That way I could disable the highlighting after `onPress` has run.
- What could be possible reasons to why the `TouchableHighlight` stays highlighted? I am using it on other parts of my app without navigation, and I could imagine that it has to do with that.

The `TouchableHighlight` exists within a FlatList. The renderItems-method looks like the following:

```
let handlePress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen');
};
return <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={handlePress}>
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>;
```

If you need/want any further information, please let me know. I've tested the code on android, using the Genymotion-emulator with Marshmallow.

Versions are:

- node -v: 8.9.4
- npm -v: 5.6.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.54.2
- react-navigation: 1.5.2
- Build environment: Windows 10 64-bit

At this point, I'm quite certain that the error is somewhere in my code, as `TouchableHighlight` works correctly on other parts of my app, and it propably has to do with the navigation-call, but I was unable to pinpoint, why exactly. I've made sure that there are no exceptions or anything like that in my app, and that the onPress-method therefore finishes successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using the tip from @Kartiikeya and exchanging `TouchableHighlight` with `TouchableOpacity` and back to `TouchableHighlight`, it now works as expected:

Now, after `onPress` has been executed, the button (be it a `TouchableOpacity` or a `TouchableHighlight`) looses its effect.

I am not sure, why it works now. The obvious reason would be, that a recompilation of the source code fixed errors - but I recompiled it for writing the original question multiple times before, so that that cannot be an option. Other users I would suggest to clear any cache possible, and especially do the following steps:

- Close and reopen the android emulator / restart your testing device
- Restart the build PC
- Recompile all source code
- Check in your console for errors and/or exceptions (obviously)
- Replace `TouchableHighlight` with `TouchableOpacity`, recompile, check if the error still exists - and if not, reexchange `TouchableOpacity` to `TouchableHighlight`

Answer (score 5):

You can replace Touchable Highlight with Touchable opacity and simply set activeOpactity prop with value 1. It will not highlight the press.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>....</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace Touchable Highlight with Touchable opacity. It won't highlight the press.

```
    return <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={handlePress}>
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity >;
```

Comment: Indeed, when switching to TouchableOpacity with the same code, the effect (here: opacity) does get removed after onPress as expected. However, this is not exactly what I wanted (the effects from TouchableHighlight fit better into the style), but definitely a helpful workaround if I dont get that working.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i needed to disable the highlight effect after onLongPress has been fired. You can simply change the key of the touchable using a re-render when you want to remove it.

Here's an example:

```
 <TouchableHighLight
   onPress={this.pressRow}
   style={styles.outerContainer}
   onLongPress={() => this.setState({ onLongPressed: true })}
   onPressOut={() => this.setState({ onLongPressed: false })}
   key={`long-pressed-${this.state.onLongPressed ? 'yes' : 'no'}`}>
  <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
    {rowText}
    {rowIcon}
  </View>
</TouchableHighLight>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Leonardo Lusoli's answer, there one thing you should also add is

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isLongPressed){
      setIsLongPressed(false)
    }
  }, [isLongPressed])
```

This step is necessary because
when the first onLongPress event is fired it will set isLongPressed to true and thus changing the key the component is re-rendered and is identifies as a new component and previour event listners are discareded so the onPressOut will not be fired. So

when isLongPressed is set to true the component re-renders and then immediatietly we set it's value to false and thus we get the expected behaviour. Otherwise we will get the unexpected behaviour followed by one expected behaviour.